# Scaling .svg in Internet Explorer 10-11

Tags: css, svg

I have problems scaling a svg in Internet Explorer 10-11. It works in other browsers.
Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">English <img src="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/gb.svg" alt=""></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li img {
    width: 19px;
    height: 13px;
}
```

How can I scale the image so that it fits to the desired width in IE10+11?

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duorz3wj/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your image in a container and specify width and height on this container.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        English 
        <div class="img-container">
          <img src="https://lipis.github.io/flag-icon-css/flags/4x3/gb.svg" alt="">
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li .img-container {
    width: 19px;
    height: 14px;
}

li img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6e47sxhg/5/